# 1 TB HDD is not visible at all after installing Ubuntu 20.04 on 256 GB SSD on Lenovo Thinkbook 15 g2 core i5 11th gen laptop

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Good day!
I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on 256 GB SSD disk(single boot). Installation progress was fine. However, I cannot see my 1TB HDD disk using Disks, Gparted, and terminal commands. I have made a research about the problem on the Internet. But they was not helpful.
Help me guys to solve that problem, please! Because I love using Ubuntu than Windows.

Comment: Does UEFI/BIOS show drive? Is it internal & AHCI or USB3? If not seen by UEFI, then no software can see it. Is it partitioned & formatted? Is it then gpt or MBR and what format of partition(s). If Windows format did Windows leave it with hibernation flag set or fast start up on set?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply dear oldfred. It is an absolutely new laptop, and all are fine with BIOS. Lenovo Thinkbook 15 g2 laptop is tested only for Ubuntu 20.04, so I do the installation for it. I now solved my problem by trying to re-install the OS.

Comment: Voted to close as "not reproducible".

Answer (score -1):

Re-installing Ubuntu 20.04 by choice that erase disk and install Ubuntu 20.04 fixed my problem. Note that I didn't do any partitioning step